# RegExp to add linebreak -> Always adds one too many

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to add line breaks into a `String`.
AKA I want lines that have a maximum of (i.e.) 100 characters.

Thanks to the people here, I already found an answer that gives me this:

```
res.replaceAll("(.{0,100}) \\b", "$1\\|");
```

(where the `|` will later be replaced with a line break)

Only problem is: the last line always ends up with a linebreak too many!

The last word of the text ALWAYS ends up in the next line. I can see why, after all, it is the last space in the last group of 100 characters; but for what I want to do, that is not acceptable, because of course the last group of 100 characters should stay together.

How do I fix this? I cannot simply remove the last linebreak, because then I may end up with a too long line.

Comment: You need to state in **this** question what you are trying to replace.

Comment: I want to replace spaces between words with a linebreak... I am unsure how this is not clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match either white space or end of the string:

```
res.replaceAll("(.{1,100})(\\s|$)\\b", "$1\\|");
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, that's logical, somehow totally missed that idea :).